# NSConcreteMutableData base64EncodedStringWithOptions error

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

I have these two errors. I developed a program that works in 10.10 but plant 10.7. I did not test in 10.8 and 10.9.
How to correct the problem.
I use these two methods for authentication and for something else.
How to do ?
Rewrite everything?
Thank you

Errors :

> 2015-09-29 10:32:47.320 PROG[1175:707] -[NSConcreteMutableData
>   base64EncodedStringWithOptions:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x7fd209e1c6b0 2015-09-29 10:32:47.321 PROG[1175:707] An
>   uncaught exception was raised 2015-09-29 10:32:47.322 PROG[1175:707]
>   -[NSConcreteMutableData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd209e1c6b0 2015-09-29 10:32:47.326
>   PROG[1175:707] (  0   CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff9158af56 **exceptionPreprocess + 198    1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x00007fff8b305d5e objc_exception_throw + 43  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00007fff916171be -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 190    3
>
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91577e23
>   ___forwarding_** + 371    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91577c38 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232  5   PROG
>   0x000000010dd8fc20 -[AppDelegate awakeFromNib] + 1056     6
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91581fb1 -[NSObject
>   performSelector:] + 49    7   CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff91581f32 -[NSSet makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 274     8
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff86eee347
>   -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 1245     9   AppKit                              0x00007fff86ee48bb loadNib + 322
>     10  AppKit                              0x00007fff86ee3db8
>   +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 217  11  AppKit                              0x00007fff86ee3cd3 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibFile:externalNameTable:withZone:] + 141  12  AppKit                              0x00007fff86ee3c16
>   +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 364   13  AppKit                              0x00007fff87154cd7 NSApplicationMain + 398  14  PROG
>   0x000000010dd8f7f2 main + 34  15  PROG
>   0x000000010dd8f7c4 start + 52     16  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) 2015-09-29 10:32:47.326 PROG[1175:707]
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteMutableData
>   base64EncodedStringWithOptions:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x7fd209e1c6b0'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9158af56 **exceptionPreprocess + 198  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x00007fff8b305d5e objc_exception_throw + 43  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00007fff916171be -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 190    3
>
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91577e23
>   ___forwarding_** + 371    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91577c38 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232  5   PROG
>   0x000000010dd8fc20 -[AppDelegate awakeFromNib] + 1056     6
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91581fb1 -[NSObject
>   performSelector:] + 49    7   CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff91581f32 -[NSSet makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 274     8
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff86eee347
>   -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 1245     9   AppKit                              0x00007fff86ee48bb loadNib + 322
>     10  AppKit                              0x00007fff86ee3db8
>   +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 217  11  AppKit                              0x00007fff86ee3cd3 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibFile:externalNameTable:withZone:] + 141  12  AppKit                              0x00007fff86ee3c16
>   +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 364   13  AppKit                              0x00007fff87154cd7 NSApplicationMain + 398  14  PROG
>   0x000000010dd8f7f2 main + 34  15  PROG
>   0x000000010dd8f7c4 start + 52     16  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 )

Thanks for your help ... and xhruso00
I do not know if I should change my question here and write a new answer ?
Thank you

With

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface NSString (NSStringExtension)

- (id) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:(NSString *)string;

- (NSString *) base64Encoding;

- (NSString *)mh_base64String;

@end
```

and

```
#import "NSStringExtension.h"

@implementation NSString (NSStringExtension)

NSUInteger  NSAppKitVersionNumber10_8;
NSUInteger NSAppKitVersionNumber;

- (NSString *)mh_base64String
{

    if (floor(NSAppKitVersionNumber) <= NSAppKitVersionNumber10_8) {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
        return [self base64Encoding];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
    }
    else {
        return [self base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    }
}

@end
```

and

in the main

```
@implementation  AppDelegate
...  




  //NSString *authenticationValue = [authenticationData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];

  NSString *authenticationValue = [authenticationData mh_base64String];

        ...
        @end
```

I have one error:

> AppDelegate.m:56:57: error: no visible @interface for 'NSData' declares
>   the selector 'mh_base64String'
>       NSString *authenticationValue = [authenticationData mh_base64String];

i have two warning :

```
    method definition for 'base64EncodedStringWithOptions:' not found 
 method definition for 'base64EncodedStringWithOptions:' not found
```

is it correct ?

What is the problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to check what OS X version you are executing you selector

Unrecognized selector base64EncodedStringWithOptions: was introduced in 10.9

> /* Create a Base-64 encoded NSString from the receiver's contents
>   using the given options.
>   */
>   - (NSString *)base64EncodedStringWithOptions:(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions)options NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 7_0);
>
> - (NSString *)base64Encoding NS_DEPRECATED(10_6, 10_9, 4_0, 7_0);

Solution A:
Create a category for the object that is loading from XIB and call the method instead of "base64EncodedStringWithOptions"

```
- (NSString *)mh_base64String
{
  if (floor(NSAppKitVersionNumber) <= NSAppKitVersionNumber10_8) {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
    return [self base64Encoding];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
  }
  else {
    return [self base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
  }
}
```

Solution B:
If you can't do category then use method swizzling of original implementation with the above implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I added the method in the method directly awakeFromNib as follows and it was ok.

thank you a lot

```
 - (void) awakeFromNib {
    ...
//NSString *authenticationValue = [authenticationData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];
    //NSString *authenticationValue = [authenticationData base64Encoding];
    NSString *authenticationValue;


    // Teste la version du système et affecte la bonne méthode
     if (floor(NSAppKitVersionNumber) <= NSAppKitVersionNumber10_8) {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
     authenticationValue = [authenticationData base64Encoding];
         // NSLog(@"--- <= 10.8 ----   %@", authenticationValue);
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
     }
     else {
     authenticationValue = [authenticationData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];
        // NSLog(@"----- >= 10.9 ---- %@", authenticationValue);
     }

    }
```